# Automapper 5.2 Nullable to Nullable Custom Generic Converter always return null

Tags: c#, automapper, nullable

My converter looks like that, and seems like if it never enters the Convert method or _source is always null. Can anybody tell me where I am wrong?

```
    class NullableToNullableConverter<T> : ITypeConverter<T?, T?> where T : struct
    {
        public T? Convert(T? source, T? destination, ResolutionContext context)
        {
            var _source = source as T?;
            if (_source.HasValue)
                return _source.Value;
            else
                return default(T?);
        }
    }
```

UPDATE:
Ok, I don't know the reason but somehow in the configuration I had the following code which placed in this order caused the Converter method not to be hit. And once reordered the conversion and the projection it started to work. What I wonder now is what is the reason for this behavior.

```
x.CreateMap<DateTime?, DateTime?>().ProjectUsing(y => y ?? default(DateTime?));
x.CreateMap<DateTime?, DateTime?>().ConvertUsing<NullableToNullableConverter<DateTime>>();
```

Comment: Have you tried using `Nullable<T>` instead of `T?` ? And could you share some code that utilizes that coverter?

Comment: x.CreateMap<DateTime?, DateTime?>().ConvertUsing<NullableToNullableConverter<DateTime>>(); is some code that utilizes it and yes I've tried Nullable<T> and it works the same way as T?

Comment: This code seems to work just fine in the [use case I tried](https://dotnetfiddle.net/IjpNdv). (You'll need to run it locally as there's no AutoMapper 5.2 installed in Fiddle.)